# tfvctemplate.12.xaml build template does not work in Azure DevOps 2019

Tags: c#, tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops-server-2019, xamlbuild

We recently migrated from TFS 2013 to Azure Devops 2019 ( on premises )
We have two servers , TFS server is running Azure DevOps 2019 and build controller is running on TFS 2010
As a result , Older XAML build are working fine.

We recently upgraded .net framework on app servers to 4.8 from earlier v 4.5

We want to use latest C# features , but not able to build those on build server.

For this , We want to use tfvctemplate.12.xaml build template which has support for C#-6 language features.

But after changing default.xaml build template to above build tfvctemplate.12.xaml template , and after queuing the builds getting below error.

**TF900558: This build process template cannot be run on build server Default Controller - TFSBUILDSVR3.  Upgrade this build server to a newer version.**

We installed Azure Devops 2019 on build controller but could not configure build controller like we did it for TFS 2010.

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: XAML build has been deprecated for years. The *replacement* for XAML is already well on its way to being phased out. If you're using stock XAML build process templates, the out-of-the-box templates for the JSON ("classic") build and YAML build cover the same ground. It's time to consider updating to something modern.

Comment: Hi there, not get your latest news. Is there any updates for this issue? Please feel free to let me know whether my comments can help you~

Comment: thanks , it helped us to decide on the next steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XAML builds are deprecated for TFS 2018 and later versions. If you want to use TFS2019, you need to migrate to the new builds.

[This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/migrate-from-xaml-builds?view=azure-devops) details the process of deprecating the old build and becoming familiar with the new builds.

Comment: Xaml builds are working in our Azure DevOps 2019 , but when we try to use a different template "tfvctemplate.12.xaml" , it shows error. ( This template is required to build C#6 code. ). I think we have two options here 

1) Migrate from XAML to YAML
2) Upgrade TFS version on Build controller server from 2010 to 2018 ( as 2018 is the last version to support XAML builds )

Question : Is there any concept of Build controller in Azure devops like earlier TFS version ?

Comment: @sagar I suggest you upgrade TFS version on Build Controller Server to TFS2013 or TFS2015. Because document shows that `tfvctemplate.12.xaml` applies to the two versions. For instructions on how to set up build Controller, refer to these two documents, [document 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/migrate-from-xaml-builds?view=azure-devops#build-defaults-tab) and [document 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ms252495(v=vs.120)).

Comment: @sagar As far as I know, Azure DevOps Server 2019 cannot set up build controller. You need to have two servers. Azure DevOps Server 2019 and TFS 2013/2015 to config build controller.